# How do I select without using rollback segments?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to export something using a select statement that runs for a very long time and I've been getting ORA-01555 snapshot too old errors. I searched for this error and it has something to do with select statement using rollback segment "redo tablespace".

How do I select without getting this error? I don't care about the integrity of the results I'm going to get or any other consequences that this may bring about.

Comment: If you don't care whether the data is consistent what's the point in doing the export at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not allow to read inconsistent results and does not provide the corresponding isolation level "read uncommitted" (if this is an isolation level at all). If you don't care about consistency, you may split the query in several parts (using different where clauses). If you would like to fix the error, you would have to resize the undo tablespace (or change the undo retention) - but this is a job for a DBA (if it is necessary).

Comment: @supertonsky - elaborating on Martin's last observation, in parentheses: *if it is necessary*. Resizing the undo tablespace and/or changing the undo retention is the right answer to your question, AFTER you rule out the obvious: your query runs very long for no good reason. There are tons of poorly written queries that run much longer than they should be, because they are poorly written. Also, in many cases well-chosen indexes would allow queries to run 10 or 100 times faster (or more), but people don't do it for various reasons (often lack of knowledge). Start there.